# Does the Change in Area Not Affect EMF Calculation in a Time-Varying Magnetic Field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I had this Question as a Homework :

> Given a conducting frame of width $$. A mobile conductor is mounted on the knitting needle that moves on the closing one at speed $\vec{} = \hat{x}$  while making electrical contact with the frame. Inside the frame there is a time-varying magnetic field $\vec{} = _0 cos() \hat{}$. What is the emf $$, that will be created in the contacts?

[image]

> Official Answer was Given as :

> $\begin{aligned}
> \mathcal{V} & =\int_L(\boldsymbol{v} \times \boldsymbol{B}) \cdot d \boldsymbol{L}-\int_S \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t} \cdot d S \\
> & =v L B_0{ }^{} \cos \omega t+\omega x L B_0 \sin \omega t \\
> & =L B_0 \sqrt{v^2+\omega^2 x^2} \sin (\omega t+\delta)
> \end{aligned}$

Issue :
I'm not sure why the Area $\Delta{x}\cdot{L}$ was not considred here in the question,
What I did was pretty similar but I considered the change in the area in the emf calculations and using Faraday's Law I got 2 expressions in the integral $-\int_S \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t} \cdot d S$.

My Solution :

(emf) $\varepsilon=-\frac{\partial \Phi_M}{\partial t}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \varepsilon_1=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_A \vec{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{d A}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \cdot(B \cdot A \cdot \cos \theta)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(B_0 \cos (\omega t) \cdot L \cdot(x+v t)\right) \\
& \varepsilon_1=-B_0 \omega \cdot \sin (\omega t) \cdot L(x+v t)-B_0 \omega \cdot \cos (\omega t) \cdot L \cdot v \\
& \mathcal{V_1} =B_0 L(w \cdot \sin (\omega t)(x+v t)-\cos (\omega t) \cdot v)  \quad \text{[V]}\\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

And for the Motion part of the emf :

$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{V_2}=\varepsilon_2=B \cdot v \cdot L=B_0 \cos \left(\omega_0 t\right) \cdot v L \quad[V]\end{aligned}$$

*My Final Answer :*
$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{V_{tot}}=\mathcal{V_1}+\mathcal{V_2}=B_0 L \cdot w \cdot \sin (\omega t)(x+v t) \quad[V]
\end{aligned}$$

***Would appreaciate help why my answer is incorrect and why the Changing area is not included when calculating.***